# Is it okay to write a cover letter with one more page

Tags: faculty-application, tenure-track, application-cover-letter

I have written a cover letter for faculty positions. I read that it need to be one page. However, mine is one page and half since i have many experience including industry and research. Is that okay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can go over one page. In fact, most cover letters for faculty searches are 2 pages. Some people go over two pages, but I don’t think it is usually necessary.